Behavior of the iterative process $f(x)=x^2-1$: divergence for $x>\phi$ and convergence to a 2-cycle for $0<x< \phi$
Behavior of the iterative process $f(x) = x^2 - 1$: divergence for $x > \phi$ and convergence to a 2-cycle for $0 < x < \phi$
I am analyzing the iterative process defined by $f(x) = x^2 - 1$, starting from an initial value $x_0$. Specifically, I am trying to prove the following two claims about the behavior of the process:

Divergence for $x > \phi$: If $x > \phi$, where $\phi = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$ (the golden ratio), then $f^n(x) \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.
Convergence to a 2-cycle for $0 < x < \phi$: If $0 < x < \phi$, the process converges to a 2-cycle between $0$ and $-1$.

What I know so far:
1. For $x > \phi$:

The fixed points of $f(x)$ are $\phi = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\psi = \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}$, the roots of $x^2 - x - 1 = 0$.
For $x > \phi$, the function satisfies $f(x) > x$, and the sequence $\{x_n\}$, defined as $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$, is monotonically increasing.
I suspect that $x_n \to \infty$, but I am unsure how to formally prove that the sequence is unbounded.

2. For $0 < x < \phi$:
I observe that the sequence $\{x_n\}$ initially alternates between the intervals $(0, \phi)$ and $(-1, 0)$. For example, if $x_n \in (0, \phi)$, then $x_{n+1} \in (-1, 0)$. However, after a finite number of iterations, the sequence $\{x_n\}$ remains in the interval $(-1, 0)$ and eventually converges to the 2-cycle $0 \to -1 \to 0$. Numerical computations confirm this behavior, but I am unsure how to rigorously prove this convergence.
Any guidance or suggestions on how to rigorously approach these proofs would be greatly appreciated!

The second part isn't quite right - there is a measure-zero set of values of $x_0$ that take you to $\psi$; one of these is $x_0=-\psi$. To prove the amended statement, though, start by showing that $f(x)<x$ for $0<x<\phi$; since there is no fixed point in this interval, you must eventually go into $[-1,0]$. Then consider the effect of $g(x)=f^2(x)$ for $-1<x<\psi$ and $\psi<x<0$.

If $x>\phi$ then $f(x)-x=x^2-x-1>0$ and $ff(x)-f(x)=x^4-2x^2+1-x^2+1$ $=x^4-3x^2+2=(x^2-1)(x^2-2)>(x+1-1)(x+1-2)=x^2-x>1$.
So $f^n(x)>n-1$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}f^n(x)=\infty$.
I'm still trying the second part...
